Using a multimeter in the Wheatstone circuit
If I make a Wheatstone circuit and connect it to my multimeter, power supply and strain gauge; I would need to read off the voltage output and then calculate the strain resistance according the equations online connecting the power supply's voltage (input) with the multimeter's voltage (output). If my understanding is correct, I cannot read the resistance values from the multimeter but only the voltage (even with increasing strain on my strain gauge). However, if you have a multimeter that cannot read small changes in voltage output (it is in mV), what should you typically do to get a good reading of the voltage output?
In the end, I want to create a deltaR over R graph of my strain gauge with different strains/forces.pressure applied to it.

Typical resistive sensors measure within a full-scale-range of several mV/V relative to the excitation voltage (though the magnitude is larger for silicon strain gage sensors), so multimeter is not the right tool for this if you want to actually do scientific measurement. Typically you use a "signal conditioner" i.e. amplifier designed for quantitative use, or a display/meter with an input circuit likewise designed for that use. These days they cost no more than a cheap multimeter
